# I want to press my button in Tkinter GUI to get iput and then get a random word from my list instead of manually typing in my input

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

Hoogte = 900
breedte = 1440


def doelwitpress(argumenten):
    if argumenten == 1:
        input("1")

    if argumenten == 2:
        input("2")


    if argumenten == 3:
        input("3")


    import random
    print('Kies uit 1 (kleinst), 2 (kleiner) of 3 (grootsts):')
    willekeurigwoord = input()

    kleinstedoelwit = ['beneficial', 'eloquent', 'in proximity']

    x = random.choice(kleinstedoelwit)

    if (willekeurigwoord == 1):
        print(x)

    kleineredoelwit = ['useful', 'advise', 'commence']
    y = random.choice(kleineredoelwit)
    if (willekeurigwoord == "2"):
        print(y)

    grootstedoelwit = ['vehicle', 'combined', 'uproar']
    z = random.choice(grootstedoelwit)

    if (willekeurigwoord == "3"):
        print(z)


root = tk.Tk()

GrafischeUIcanvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=Hoogte)
GrafischeUIcanvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=breedte)


GrafischeUIcanvas.pack()

achtergrondkleur = tk.Frame(root, bg='#6BAB55')
achtergrondkleur.place(relwidt=1, relheight=1)

kleinstedoelwit = tk.Button(root, text="kleinste doelwit", command=lambda: doelwitpress(1))
kleineredoelwit = tk.Button(root, text="kleinere doelwit", command=lambda: doelwitpress(2))
grootstedoelwit = tk.Button(root, text="grootste doelwit", command=lambda: doelwitpress(3))


kleinstedoelwit.pack(side="left")
kleineredoelwit.pack(side="bottom")
grootstedoelwit.pack(side="right")

root.mainloop()
```

when i only run my code without gui i can get a word out but i have to manually type it in. I want my tkinter button to be my input and get an output from my code. I basically want to press a button in the UI, the UI then inputs a number and that number equals to one of the lists whith random words. The only thing that happens right now is that it shows the input of my press and then it crashes after 1 input. It doesnt even display 1 random chosen word.
Im using tkinter and random.choice

Comment: You should not use console `input()` in a GUI application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `Entry` widget to get the input from the user and `Label` or a `messagebox` to display output.

I have rewritten your code, without changing any logic. (Note: This is only for demonstration purposes as I have no idea how your GUI should come together. It's up to you to make further changes)

In the below code, I have set `entry` and `entry2` to a variable `var` and `var1` respectively. You can use this variable to get and set the value in the `Entry` widget as shown in the below code.

For output, I have used a label. You may change the text by using `label.config(text='abc')` or `label.configure(text='abc')` or just by accessing the text like `lable[text] = 'abc'`

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

Hoogte = 900
breedte = 1440


def doelwitpress(argumenten):
    if argumenten == 1:
        var.set('1')

    if argumenten == 2:
        var.set('2')

    if argumenten == 3:
        var.set('3')


    lbl['text'] = 'Kies uit 1 (kleinst), 2 (kleiner) of 3 (grootsts):'
    #print('Kies uit 1 (kleinst), 2 (kleiner) of 3 (grootsts):')
    #willekeurigwoord = input()

    kleinstedoelwit = ['beneficial', 'eloquent', 'in proximity']

    x = random.choice(kleinstedoelwit)

    if (var2.get() == '1'):
        lbl['text'] = x
        #print(x)

    kleineredoelwit = ['useful', 'advise', 'commence']
    y = random.choice(kleineredoelwit)
    if (var2.get() == "2"):
        lbl['text'] = y
        #print(y)

    grootstedoelwit = ['vehicle', 'combined', 'uproar']
    z = random.choice(grootstedoelwit)

    if (var2.get() == "3"):
        lbl['text'] = z
        #print(z)


root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar()
var2 = tk.StringVar()

GrafischeUIcanvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=Hoogte)
GrafischeUIcanvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=breedte)

GrafischeUIcanvas.pack()


achtergrondkleur = tk.Frame(root, bg='#6BAB55')
achtergrondkleur.place(relwidt=1, relheight=1)
#achtergrondkleur.pack()

kleinstedoelwit = tk.Button(root, text="kleinste doelwit", command=lambda: doelwitpress(1))
kleineredoelwit = tk.Button(root, text="kleinere doelwit", command=lambda: doelwitpress(2))
grootstedoelwit = tk.Button(root, text="grootste doelwit", command=lambda: doelwitpress(3))

kleinstedoelwit.pack(side="left")
kleineredoelwit.pack(side="bottom")
grootstedoelwit.pack(side="right")

lbl = tk.Label(root, bg='#6BAB55', fg='red')
lbl.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
entry.pack()

entry2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var2)
entry2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```